# Customize dynamic dialog PRIMNG

Tags: modal-dialog, angular7

How i can customize dynamic dialog template from PrimNG?
I follow this guide https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog .
I want to customize footer part with my own template, but i don`t no how it do.
Help please) 
Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no way to achieve that. You're better off using showHeader: false, removing all the paddings and using the p-dialog-content as you main content where you can define whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize on the main css file like this:

```
body .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #20252e;
}
```